# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:Trying to submit data

Tags: forms, laravel

I created a form and I am trying to submit data, but error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

is coming. What to do?

welcome blade:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
Welcome!!
@endsection

@section('content')
@include('includes.message-block')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Enter Your Information</h2>
          <form action="" method="post">    
            <div class="form-group" {{$errors -> has('name') ? 'has-error': ''}}>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" {{$errors -> has('email') ? 'has-error': ''}}>
                <label for="email">Email-Id</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="branch">Branch</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="branch" id="branch" placeholder="Enter Your Branch">
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="course_name">Course Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="course_name" id="course_name" placeholder="Enter Your Course">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">                
        </form> 
    </div>
@endsection
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
protected $table = 'students';

}
```

UserController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Flash;
use InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
use Flash;
//use Mail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersstudents;

class UserController extends Controller

{

 public function postData(Request $request)
 {
    $this -> validate($request,[
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:students',
      'name'  => 'required|max:20',
      'branch'  => 'required|max:10'
      'course_name'  => 'required|max:10'
      ]);

    $email = $request['email'];
    $name = $request['name'];
    $branch = $request['branch'];
    $course_name = $request['course_name'];



    $student = new User();
    $student->email =$email;
    $student->name = $name;
    $student->branch = $branch;
    $student->course_name = $course_name;


    $student->save();

    return redirect()->back();

 }
}
```

Route/web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/submit_data',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@postData',
    'as' => 'submit_data'
    ]);
});
```

Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('mail')->unique();
        $table -> string('name');
        $table -> string('branch');
        $table -> string('course_name');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('students');
}
}
```

My migration's name is create_users_table. I don't understnad why this error is coming. It's an easy and simple form.Just a simple form to submit a students data, and save it in database.

Comment: Your `action` prop in `<form action="" method="post"> ` is empty, you should try to add the route you configured: `<form action="/submit_data" method="post">`

Answer (score 1):

**You are posting to a `get` route**

In your `welcome.blade.php` you forgot to set your `action`, so by default it will try to post to the same page `/` which is definded as a `get` route in your `routes/web.php`. Set the action to `/submit_data` like so in your `welcome.blade.php`:

```
<form action="{{ url('/submit_data') }}" method="post">
```

Comment: Thank you, I did that, but another error : QueryException in Connection.php line 761:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'larw.students' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `students` where `email` = shefali195sharma@gmail.com)

Comment: I have changed my database to "database", my database's name. larw was my older database.I don't understand why is this error coming when i have changed my database's name.

Comment: As the error states `Table 'larw.students' doesn't exist` the table you are querying does not exist. Did you run your migrations?

Comment: Yes, I did it. actually, larw don't even exist now

Comment: Check your `.env` file for the right database parameters

Comment: In my .env file: 
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

should i use another name for my database?

Comment: Are you using those parameters in your `database.php` file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126300/discussion-between-jhonny-walker-and-shefali-sharma).

Comment: I changed my database name to userdata, but smae error is coming.. database.php file?.. for what?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{{ url('submit_data') }}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use blade from like this

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'/submit_data','files'=>true,'class'=>'form-horizontal','file'=>'true'))}}
```